# スペースを含んだクラス名を jquery で指定できない

Tags: jquery

jquery でDOM要素をクラス名で指定するとき、クラス名にスペースが含まれているとうまく指定できません

```
<div class="A B C">
  <p>first</p>
</div>
<div class="A C">
  <p>second</p>
</div>
```

このようなHTMLをが存在した時

`$("div.A.C").html()`

と指定しても

`<p>first</p>`

が帰ってきてしまいます

`<p>second</p>`

を取得するにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("div.A.C:not(.B)").html()
```

Answer (score 6):

HTMLのclass属性には、スペースで区切った複数のクラスを指定することができます。

つまり、`<div class="A B C">` はA・B・Cの3つのクラス、`<div class="A C">` はA・Cの2つのクラスとして解釈されます。クラス「A B C」という意味にはなりません。そしてCSSやjQueryのセレクタ記法で `$("div.A.C")` と書いた場合、AとBの両方のクラスを持った `<div>` 要素という意味ですから、`<div class="A B C">` `<div class="A C">` の両方に該当します。

この場面で `<div class="A C">` だけを選択するには、「クラスBを持っていない」という条件も付ける必要があります。それがemasakaさんの書かれている `:not(.B)` という記述です。

属性全般で使えるセレクタを使えば、スペースも含めてマッチさせることもできますが、class属性の使い方としては適切ではないでしょう。